# How to find circle inside Rectangle in AForge

Tags: c#, aforge

I am trying to detect Circle inside Rectangle in `AForge`. I have successfully determined `Rectangles` but unable to find `circles` inside `Rectangle`. How to find shape inside another shape in `AForge`.

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/Recipt001.png");
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(strPath);

//Some filters Grayscale, invert, threshold

//Blod Filtering                      


BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
blobCounter.ProcessImage(temp);
blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.YX;
blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;

Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

// dictionary of color to highlight different shapes
Dictionary<PolygonSubType, Color> colors = new Dictionary<PolygonSubType, Color>();

colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Unknown, Color.White);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Trapezoid, Color.Orange);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Parallelogram, Color.Red);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Rectangle, Color.Green);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Square, Color.Blue);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.Rhombus, Color.Gray);

colors.Add(PolygonSubType.EquilateralTriangle, Color.Pink);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.IsoscelesTriangle, Color.Purple);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.RectangledTriangle, Color.SkyBlue);
colors.Add(PolygonSubType.RectangledIsoscelesTriangle, Color.SeaGreen);

for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
{
    List<IntPoint> corners;
    List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);
    Point center;
    double radius;

    if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out corners))
    {
        if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners) == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
        {
            g.DrawPolygon(redPen, ToPointsArray(corners));
        }
    }
}

redPen.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to make a square with corners on circumference of a circle.  The circle would then be outside of the square and you need the circle to be on the inside of the square.

Comment: @jdweng No, I have recognized rectangles. Now those rectangles have circles inside them. Now I want to get those circles inside rectangle.

Comment: @jdweng I have drwan a polygon on detected rectangles for testing purpose only. Now those shapes have circles inside them.

Comment: Try to use Hough circle transorm for resolving of your problem. See [HoughCircleTransformation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/9b9aedc2-0048-acc8-4d35-0e41788d69da.htm) class. You may extract radius from rectangle size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of image processing libraries and even image processing in MATLAB lets you search ROI inside ROI (*ROI - region of intrest like rectangles or circles*). Concept is **CROP REGION -> SEARCH OBJECTS IN REGION**

So first locate primary rectangles, thereafter crop image to rectangles and perform circle search inside them. Otherwise search for all circles and all rectangles and then classify circles to be belonging to which rectangle using simple maths.

Comment: well I have already done this solution. I have found rectangles. Than I am cropping it from an image and doing process on that image for circles. But I am looking for solution in AForge. I wonder Aforge might have solution to this problem directly rather than this hack.

Comment: This is not an Hack, this is the way libraries are designed. So be enlightened you've found the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) . I am searching for AForge and reading their forum and looking into details how they assume this behavior.